# Increase thread number and looping through them until condition is met

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, is there any way in which I can gradually increase the thread number (with each thread looping the request lifecycle forever), until condition is met? When the condition is met, the entire test should stop.

My test is now as follows:
-- Stepping thread group
-- while condition
-- Request

But with this configuration, when the while condition is met, the user that met the condition stops looping, but I want the entire test to end.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be just adding a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the While Controller and configure it like:

[image]

this way the first user which will exit the loop will stop all the threads, when the last thread is stopped the whole test ends.

Alternatively if you're using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the While Controller's condition you can add the following line to it:

```
ctx.getPreviousResult().setStopTest(true)
```

where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands.